# Can't get eslint-plugin-css-modules too work. Keeps complaining about my usage of :local(.className)

Tags: eslint, css-modules

I am trying to get my eslint-plugins-css-modules plugin too work.

I am new too linting in general and may not have set this up correctly.

The exact error I get is about:

Parsing error: Unexpected token

The error is at the ':'

I have a scss file as follows:

```
:local(.onlineUsersWidget) {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And an eslintrc like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:jest/recommended",
        "plugin:css-modules/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "css-modules"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*test.js"],
            "rules": {
                "react/display-name": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```